# Error: <no source info>: public class org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource

Tags: java, maven, apache-commons-dbcp

This error (with all related 'unresolved type' errors) appeared while installing Maven project. There were no changes related to dbcp, I tried to delete all the local repos, installed again and `commons-dbcp` was downloaded, so dependencies are fine I suppose (actually I could install with the same dependencies a couple of hours ago). What could be a reason of such behaviour?

Comment: May be incomplete download resulted into corrupted file

Comment: @JigarJoshi Well, at first this error appeared with libraries that were downloaded earlier and gave no errors.

Comment: Are you using a repository manager or do you have a proxy between you and the internet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in this case I had a problem because of a unused import of the server-side class in one of the presenters (that I had put there by mistake and then forgot about), probably it was a reason of an attempt to autowire a bean that was in the application context and it was just not the right time for it.